# Why does cpuinfo show only 2 processors?

Tags: centos, cpu

I'm running the following command:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | /bin/egrep 'processor|model name|cache size|core|sibling|physical'
```

Which gives this output:

```
processor   : 0
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
processor   : 1
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 4
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

So I can tell Hyperthreading is ON, given the `ht` flag in the full cpuinfo output, and also because siblings are twice the cpu cores.

Does this mean I have one physical quad core processor with HT enabled and that's it?

It's not clear to me why there are only 2 processor records listed (core ids 0 and 1). Shouldn't there be 2 other records for cores 2 and 3?

*Note: Running lscpu gives me an error "failed to determine number of CPUs"

Comment: Hi @jk33 would you pelase run this command `nproc --all` what is the output

Comment: Output says 16.

Comment: Are you running this inside a VM?

Comment: Nope this is a dedicated server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` above you can see the following information:

```
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
```

Looking at this [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/products/40200/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5520-8M-Cache-2_26-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI) page about your processor specification, It is clear that your processor has 4 cores. So, `cpuinfo` is correct.

Also, you can see the count of siblings is 8 and cpu cores are 4. cpu cores being 4 is that total number of cores in the processor.

Most new processors are designed to save power and battery, meaning not necessary that all the cores are running at the same time. The contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` is somewhat implementation dependent and misleading, so it is not necessary to correctly report the hardware information. In fact, `/proc/cpuinfo` is one of the few places in Linux where you get complete information about what hardware you have.

In order to count the correct number of CPUs Use the command `[nproc][1]` which is part of coreutils. This command prints the number of processing units available to the current process.

To find the number of all installed cores/processors, run the command [nproc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nproc.1.html)as follows:

```
nproc --all
--all  print the number of installed processors
```

More information about `/proc/cpuinfo` and the number of processors can be reached [here](http://doc.callmematthi.eu/static/webArticles/Understanding%20Linux%20_proc_cpuinfo.pdf)